# How to add type annotations to a decorator for a class instance method that has been decorated with functools.wraps?

Tags: python, wrapper, python-decorators

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")
R = TypeVar("R")

def deco(func: Callable[Concatenate[R, int, int,  P], None]):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        return func(self, 1, 2, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class A:
    @deco
    def main(self, a, b, c):
        pass


a = A()
a.main(3)
```

Last line of code, pyright gives me an error message: `Argument missing for parameter "c"`

It is ok when I remove the `@functools.wraps(func)`

How to solve this error message while keeping `@functools.wraps(func)`?

Thanks in advance

The code structure cannot be changed, so I actually can't try anything, and I have no idea.

Comment: `functools.wraps` isn't really supposed to be used with signature-changing decorators. The wrapper is assumed to have the same signature as what it wraps.

Comment: I see no error on python 3.10.12

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins Actually, this is not a syntax error. This code can work perfectly. This is an error message from pyright, which is related to type annotations.

Comment: Did you mean to use default value for `a` and `b` but not `c`? Try swapping them or make them keyword-only instead.